# How to get simple list of devices on a Nest account using Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, nest-api

Is there a way to just get a simple list of the devices on a Nest account when using the Firebase API in Android?

I've looked through the NestDK that they have, and I can't find any way to just simply get all the devices after authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all the devices by making an HTTP GET call to https://developer-api.nest.com/devices

There is also an updates Android Library here: https://github.com/nestlabs/android-sdk